# Two valued logic, expressions, languages and predicates

Tags: logic

Logic usually talk about expressions P or Q. It is assumed that a given expression P is true or false.

But and expression is written using a specific language.

This language has an universal Turing machine that define the language.

Within this language expression are predicates.

Given a predicate written in this language we cannot guarantee that we will be able to evaluate them.

It doesn't matter which evaluator we choose, any predicate would be true, false or bottom.

So our initial assumption that an expression would be always true or false doesn't hold.

Is there anything wrong in this explanation?

Comment: Logic talks about formulas which eventually become either true or false when taking an interpretation *in a model*. Turing machines are *different entities* as formulas.

Comment: For *first-order* logic (i.e. "predicate logic" versus "propositional logic"), formulas *don't* "evaluate" (really "get interpreted as") "true" or "false". We could, at best, say that for *closed* formulas (i.e. ones with no free variables). The typical semantics used for classical first-order logic interprets formulas as set-theoretic relations. This involves a bunch of uncomputable stuff on its face. What we *could* talk about computing is the *provability* relation, but this isn't about "evaluating" formulas.

Comment: You may find the earlier sections of [this article](https://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/the-pedagogy-of-logic-a-rant.html) by me helpful. You do seem to have the mindset described in those sections that sees "logical formula[s as] 'expressions' which 'compute' to true or false".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would need some time to unlearn. I feel totally identified with the misunderstandings you mention. I would keep that in mind when rereading fundamentals.

Comment: I think I had some serious misunderstanding of what it means true and false in classic logic (ie universally valid and nothing else). To any logician, how can you talk with normal people? Type theory seems more open minded...but it would take me several weeks to get the definitions in my crappy hardware...

Answer (score 1):

''Given a predicate written in this language we cannot guarantee that we will be able to evaluate them.''

If you have written a predicate, say $P(n)$ with free parameter $n$, in a programming language, then plugging in a value $n=n_0$, the predicate can be assumed to be evaluated to a proposition $P(n_0)$, true or false.

You either refer to the satisfiability problem (NP-hard) or undecidability of first order predicate calculus.

Comment: As predicates I was refering to functions from language to bool. The evaluator is a program (maybe written in any other language) that evaluates this predicates...

Comment: Can I write a single program that it would be able to evaluate any given predicate as input and always return true or false?

Comment: Probably I don t fully understand undecidability. But if a program like evaluator exist it can be used to prove any  given statement , isn't it?